# How to make bundles hook into another bundle?

Tags: symfony

Let's say I'm building a admin bundle or anything similar. I want this admin bundle to be able to pretty much only function with that it makes it possible for other bundles to "hook" into the menu, create their own pages and similar.

How would one approach this kind of solutions?
Let's for example take the menu, inside the Admin Bundle. How would other bundles hook into that, with their own menu item, and when you click on that specific button, showing their own admin content.

Kind of how many CMS works, WordPress, Magento etc.

Could someone make a general explanation about the concepts surrounding bundles "sharing" information, extending each other?

Answer (score 0):

Symfony is HTTP based. You can do this by doing a service description. This process uses "EventDispatcher". You create a "click, hover vs" event as if it were in the same JavaScript. Then you trigger these events on a different bundle. This is how Symfony "KnpMenuBundle" works.